# Django Rest Framework very slow when accessing user properties

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Everytime I make a drf request to access user properties, such as:

```py
def StatusView(request):
    current_user = request.user
    if current_user.is_anonymous:
        return HttpResponse("none", content_type="text/plain")
    # return HttpResponse(JsonResponse(Serialize_User(current_user)), content_type="text/plain")
    # tmp = Serialize_User(current_user)
    return HttpResponse("none", content_type="text/plain")
```

it takes up to 10 seconds to get a response.
If I comment out this line `if current_user.is_anonymous:`, the request is instant. Same goes for `tmp = Serialize_User(current_user)`. Any kind of user access takes too long to process. 
I looked into optimization methods, but disabling `DEBUG` or prefetching doesn't help, as my models don't include nested models. 
Here is my `User` model:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    #avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the short name for the user.
        '''
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        Sends an email to this User.
        '''
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

Is there any way to solve or debug this issue?

Edit:
Here is the profiling panel when using django debug toolbar for `StatusView`:

```
Call    CumTime Per TotTime Per Count
- /debug_toolbar/panels/__init__.py in process_request(165)
10.320  10.320  0.000   0.000   1
- /django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner(31)
10.320  10.320  0.000   0.000   1
- /django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response(85)
10.320  10.320  0.000   0.000   1
- /var/www/cnmb10a/cnmb10a/rest/auth_api/views.py in StatusView(69)
10.320  10.320  0.000   0.000   1
- /django/utils/functional.py in inner(254)
10.315  10.315  0.000   0.000   1
- /django/utils/functional.py in _setup(391)
10.315  10.315  0.000   0.000   1
- /django/contrib/auth/middleware.py in <lambda>(24)
10.315  10.315  0.000   0.000   1
- /django/contrib/auth/middleware.py in get_user(10)
10.315  10.315  0.000   0.000   1
- /django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in get_user(174)
10.315  10.315  0.000   0.000   1
- /django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in _get_user_session_key(56)
10.221  10.221  0.000   0.000   1
 /django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in __getitem__(53)
10.221  10.221  0.000   0.000   1
```

Edit2:
I've tried using the default database system that came with django and it works fine, but as soon as I switch to the mysql database hosted on the same machine, all the requests that access it take 10 seconds. I don't know where the issue is, as the database works fine when making calls through regular php, or phpadmin, or terminal.

Comment: Can you add the django debug toolbar and see what the rendering time is as well as the sql time?

Comment: Using debug toolbar, the website manages 3 sql requests in 3.69ms. I don't know where to see render time, but it should be fine since all navigation works very fast. Only rest framework calls that access user data seem to be slow.

Comment: Typically near the Template panel I believe. You can activate the Profiling panel to see a better breakdown of what's taking so long.

Comment: Does it always take 10 seconds and change? Are you sure there isn't a `sleep(10)` somewhere?

Comment: Also: does the Django admin, etc. that uses `request.user` too also take that long?

Comment: Django admin also takes 10 seconds minimum per request. I don't think there's any ```sleep```, I searched inside the whole project. If there is one though, maybe it's inside native files which I have not touched, and I don't know where I should search for that

Comment: Could you try the same on just a local development database such as sqlite so we can rule out the engine please?

Comment: It seems the issue actually is with the database. As soon as I switched to the default database, everything worked instantly. I don't know why that is, unfortunately, because database calls are instant through php or the terminal

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I'm having exactly the same problem but with a postgress DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem for me was using `localhost` as the host for my database. When I used `127.0.0.1` instead, everything seemed to work normally

Comment: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` _should_ be synonymous.

Comment: I know, but this is just what worked for me. Might have been something to do with my machine configuration.